# Merge conflict with .DS_Store on Mac

Tags: git, git-merge, gitignore

I've been working on a repository for over a year with no issues. Someone else committed to it for the first time, and when I tried to pull their changes, I got this message:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    .DS_Store
```

I can't find a file called `.DS_Store` anywhere in my repository. I added `.DS_Store` to my `.gitignore` and committed those changes, but I'm still getting the error. Then I tried running `git stash` before `git pull` but that also didn't help. How do I fix it?

Working in RStudio on a Macbook Pro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Someone else committed to it for the first time ...

["Well, there's your problem!"](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/well-theres-your-problem)

Seriously, what happened is that this *someone else* put *their* `.DS_Store` file into *their* commit.  You accepted their commit, so you accepted the idea that `.DS_Store` should be stored in your Git repository, in that commit.  (You might consider ejecting this commit from every copy of the repository that *you* control, and making them re-do it correctly, or you might just fix it for them in every repository that you control by extracting their commit somewhere safe, removing the file, and making a new additional commit.  Note that you must then carefully avoid ever *checking out* their commit anywhere this would be "unsafe".)

As [SwissCodeMen said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70467328/1256452), `.DS_Store` is a hidden file that the macOS Finder creates and uses to store information about where and how to display various icons for various files and sub-directories within a directory (or folder if you prefer that term).  *Yours* records what *you* want shown and where; *theirs* records what *they* want shown and where; and you probably don't want theirs and they probably don't want yours.  However, this sort of thing is pretty harmless when overwritten: you can just remove it and let Finder create one from scratch.  You'll lose any careful re-organization you did to put your icons where *you* wanted them, though.

#### The key concept here is that a commit holds a snapshot of all files

*Every* commit in *every* Git repository stores *every file*.  There are a bunch of things to know about this, depending on what level of Git mastery you want.  The minimum set you need to know just to *use* Git is this:

- A repository is, at its heart, a collection of commits.  A Git repository is not about *files*, though commits contain files.  A repository is not about *branches*, though commits are arranged in things we call branches, and different things that we *also* call branches—or more precisely, branch *names*—help us (and Git) *find* the commits.  But in the end the repository is about the commits.
- Each commit has a unique, but random-looking and impossible to remember, "number", expressed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal).  This number is unique to *that particular commit:* no other Git repository—anywhere, for any purpose—may use *that* number unless it's to store *that one particular commit.*<sup>1</sup>  This is how two different Git clones, upon meeting each other, decide which commits one has that the other lacks.
- Each commit stores two things:

  - A commit stores a *snapshot of all files*, as in this section.  The files inside the commit are stored in a special way though: they're compressed—sometimes very much so—and Git-ified, and *de-duplicated*.  If the same file is in millions of commits, it's only stored *once*.  So even though Git stores every version of every file, each version only has one copy, and sometimes that one copy is reduced to just a few bytes.

    Note that, although it sounds funny when put this way, a commit stores only *the files that it stores*.  That is, commit `A` (`A` standing in for some hash ID) might be your very first commit, where you had just a `README.md` file or some such.  So commit `A` has only that one file, or that file plus a few other skeleton startup files.  The *next* commit `B` might have more files in it, but `A` only has the initial files.
  - A commit stores some *metadata*, or information about the commit itself.  That includes stuff like who made it, when, and why (their log message).  The metadata string commits together, so that Git can find one commit from another commit.
- Every commit, once made, is completely read-only.  (This is actually true of all of Git's internal objects and is due to the hash-ID-based storage trick.)

Because a commit *is* read-only, and has Git-ified files that only Git can read and literally nothing—not even Git itself—can overwrite, you *must* **extract** a commit before you can work on or with it.  The extracted, to-be-worked-on copy is not the commit itself: it's a copy.  This copy goes in your working tree, where you do your work.

When you go to extract a copy of a commit, Git will, in general, overwrite your *previous* working tree copy.  That is, Git has to throw out all the *old* files from the *previously selected* commit, and replace them with the *new* copies from the *newly selected* commit.

For some files—your *untracked* files, whether they're ignored or not—Git can just leave the files alone.  That's great for you, most of the time: it means your macOS Finder can drop various `.DS_Store` files all over your working tree, and as long as you don't *add and commit* the files so that they never go into any *commit* in your repository, Git never disturbs these working-tree files.

But some files *are* in commits.  Here, if some files *F1* and *F2* are in current commit `C`, and you're switching to new target commit `T` that has the *same copy* of *F1* but a *different copy* of *F2*, Git is going to have to rip file *F2* out of your working tree and put in the `T` version of *F2*.

The same goes for a `.DS_Store` file: if your co-worker / colleague / someone else made a commit that holds some `.DS_Store` file, and your current commit `C` *doesn't* have a `.DS_Store` file but your working tree *does* have one, you have an *untracked* `.DS_Store` file.  **Note that it does not matter if this file is ignored or not; what matters is that you have it in your working tree, and there's a copy of a file named `.DS_Store` in the target commit `T` too.**  You've told Git to switch to commit `T`, from current commit `C`, so Git has to *remove* **your** (untracked) `.DS_Store` and put in **their** `.DS_Store` from `T`.

Git—rightly!—complains that it will overwrite, i.e., discard, your `.DS_Store` file.  And it will, if you check out commit `T`.  Your options are:<sup>2</sup>

- check out commit `T`, overwriting your `.DS_Store` file anyway;
- move or save your `.DS_Store` first so that overwriting is no longer a problem, *then* check out commit `T`; or
- don't check out commit `T`.

Note that you cannot fix commit `T` because no commit can ever be changed.  You can make a *new and improved version* of `T` by checking it out, *removing* the `.DS_Store` file, and making a new commit `T2`, but when you do that, your existing `.DS_Store` file will be overwritten briefly until you remove it.  (You can then put your untracked `.DS_Store` file back from wherever you saved it, if you like.)

If saving and restoring your `.DS_Store` file is particularly painful for some reason—it probably isn't, but there might be other files for which this might be the case—consider using `git worktree add` to add a temporary working tree and branch, in which you do the fixup commit to make corrected commit `T2`, without touching your existing working tree.  Do this with the command line, without using any fancy GUI including the macOS Finder, so that Finder won't use the `.DS_Store` file *in* the temporary added working tree.  This add-a-working-tree technique lets you use all the usual everyday Git tools without having to learn a lot of deeper Git commands.

---

<sup>1</sup>This technical requirement for uniqueness is technically impossible—provably so, via the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)—but the huge *size* of a commit hash ID helps put off the inevitable disaster; we hope that it doesn't happen until after the universe ends, or at least we're all dead and don't care.  If and when it *does* happen, <s>the universe is destroyed</s> er no <s>the Rapture occurs</s> uh wait that's not right <s>we all turn into frogs?</s> ah yes: the two Git repositories in which there's a hash collision of this sort can't talk to each other any more.  So, not really all that much of a disaster, just pretty annoying.

<sup>2</sup>Technically, there are several more options.  For instance, you could use:

- *sparse checkout,* to avoid checking out the one file before removing the file and committing to make `T2`; or
- `git read-tree`, `git rm --cached`, `git write-tree`, and `git commit-tree` to literally avoid checking out commit `T` while making commit `T2`.

These are pretty tricky to explain and it's better for most people to just use regular Git operations.

Answer (score 4):

`.DS_Store` is a hidden file (because the `.`) and you can‘t just see it. In the terminal, you can see it with `ls -la`.

Then, if you have already once push `.DS_Store` to your repo, you must *untrack* this file, then only *untracked* files will be ignored with `.gitignore`.

To untrack a file/folder, execute `git rm --cached .DS_Store`. Then, when `.DS_Store` is correct registered in `.gitignore`, you will never see this file on your remote repository.

But there is also no problem, to overwritte the `.DS_Store`-file with a merge. These file contain information about system configuration. And for every person where someting push to this repository from a Mac OS, will create the own `.DS_Store`. But with correct adding to `.gitignore`, this file is no longer overwritten every time.

Comment: Thanks! I do see `.DS_Store` when I run `ls -la`, but when I run `git rm --cached .DS_Store`, I get this error: fatal: `pathspec '.DS_Store' did not match any files`. I also can't see .DS_Store in Finder even when viewing hidden files, so I can't think of another way to delete it.